# kvm error: Cannot find suitable CPU model for given data

Tags: kvm-virtualization

I'm getting the error when trying to create a VM in my Debian Jessie install. It's new, suggesting a bug, but would like to see if there is a fix first. Some info:

```
cpuinfo: processor       : 7
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 58
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1230 V2 @ 3.30GHz
```

Install script:

```
virt-install -n altair -r 1024 --vcpus 1 \
        --description='rhel7 DR development' \
        -l http://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/centos/7/os/x86_64/ \
        --os-type=linux --os-variant=rhel7 \
        --disk pool=vg,bus=virtio,size=40 \
        --network bridge=br0,model=virtio \
        --autostart \
        --nographics \
        -x "console=hvc0 \
inst.sshd ks=http://172.16.100.1/ks/altair.cfg"
```

virsh capabilities: https://gist.github.com/neilhwatson/3e26a0907c1582aff7bf

Comment: can you post the output or `virsh capabilities`?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and this worked for me :

https://www.mail-archive.com/debian-bugs-dist@lists.debian.org/msg1273522.html

```
rm -rf /var/cache/libvirt/qemu/capabilities/*
```

And after a reboot it was fine.

Answer (score 0):

When I was having this issue I disabled apparmor in `/etc/libvirt/qemu.conf`: `security_driver = "none"`